# Submitting a nested form, weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, forms, nested-forms

I have a ad banner that has a form and this is used by 3rd party site owners that grab this code and have this banner on there site.

Since some sites that use this banner have a `<form>` wrapping there entire site I have found that the banners form doesn't submit it rather submits the outer form.

#### Here is the code:

```
  <form onSubmit="return alert('outer form submitted')">

    <!-- only if i add this empty form it submits the inner -->
         <form></form>
    <!-- End Empty form -->

    <!-- inner form -->
      <form onSubmit="return alert('inner form submitted')" > 
           <input type="submit" /> 
      </form> 
    <!--end  inner form -->

 </form>
```

As you can see only if I add a empty `<form>`  before the inner `<form>` it alert (submits) the inner, otherwise it submits the outer.

What is the best way to code a banner ad for a site with a form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a <form> inside a <form> is malformed HTML, and all bets are off how any browser/user-agent/javascript-engine/dom implementation is going to handle it. Expect wildly different or equal results between different visitors. Just don't have a <form> in a <form>. Period :)

Most likely scenario in your observed behavior: starting a <form> tag inside a form is probably 'discarded' as invalid, including any actions/events (but probably not <input>s), the first </form> closes the 'main' form.

Comment: (+1) Wrikken is dead on.  Just don't do this.

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks! so what is the best way to code a banner ad for a site with a form?

Comment: Don't use a form for something that's just a link?

Comment: I'd wouldn't even consider putting plain HTML from an advertiser on my HTML pages, consider the security implications! (And you just broke my form). Ads should be either single elements (flash and/or image/url pairs) under the siteowners control, or if more is needed load it in an iframe. The fact you can even run javascript in someone elses page, and even more so, are allowed to, baffles me.

Comment: @Gareth I don't get what you are trying to say, Please explain.